# boost.parameter and constructors

Tags: c++, boost, parameters

In the documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html#parameter-enabled-constructors

Do I understand correctly, that I can't use parameter names without using base-class, as shown in the example?

Because macro BOOST_PARAMETER_CONSTRUCTOR, as the second argument requires the name of base-class to be specified.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be correct. 123